# My Merkle Tree calculation does not match the actual one

Tags: python, sha256, bitcoin, merkle-tree

I am studying bitcoin.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#Merkle_Trees

I read the above URL and implemented Merkle root in Python.

Using the API below, I collected all transactions in block 641150 and calculated the Merkle Root.

https://www.blockchain.com/explorer/api/blockchain_api

The following is the expected value
`67a637b1c49d95165b3dd3177033adbbbc880f6da3620498d451ee0976d7b1f4`
(https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block/641150 )

The values I calculated were as follows
`f2a2207a1e8360b75729fd2f23659b1b79b14940b6e4982a985cf6aa6f941ad7`

What is wrong?

My python code is;

```
from hashlib import sha256
import requests, json

base_url = 'https://blockchain.info/rawblock/'
block_hash = '000000000000000000042cef688cf40b4a70ac814e4222e6646bd6bb79d18168'
end_point = base_url + block_hash

def reverse(hex_be):
    bytes_be = bytes.fromhex(hex_be)
    bytes_le = bytes_be[::-1]
    hex_le = bytes_le.hex()
    return hex_le
    
def dhash(hash):
    return sha256(sha256(hash.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest().encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

def culculate_merkle(hash_list):

    if len(hash_list) == 1:
        return dhash(hash_list[0])

    hashed_list = list(map(dhash, hash_list))

    if len(hashed_list) % 2 == 1:
        hashed_list.append(hashed_list[-1])
    
    parent_hash_list = []
        
    it = iter(hashed_list)
    for hash1, hash2 in zip(it, it):
        parent_hash_list.append(hash1 + hash2)

    hashed_list = list(map(dhash, hash_list))
    return culculate_merkle(parent_hash_list)

data = requests.get(end_point)
jsondata = json.loads(data.text)
tx_list = list(map(lambda tx_object: tx_object['hash'], jsondata['tx']))

markleroot = '67a637b1c49d95165b3dd3177033adbbbc880f6da3620498d451ee0976d7b1f4'

tx_list = list(map(reverse, tx_list))

output = culculate_merkle(tx_list)
output = reverse(output)
print(output)
```

result

```
$ python merkleTree.py
f2a2207a1e8360b75729fd2f23659b1b79b14940b6e4982a985cf6aa6f941ad7
```

I expect the following output as a result

`67a637b1c49d95165b3dd3177033adbbbc880f6da3620498d451ee0976d7b1f4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self solving

first:
There was mistake in the dhash calculation method.
second:
The hash list obtained from the API had already had the dhash applied once.
⇒ The first time dhash was performed without this perspective

The complete source code is summarized in the following blog (in Japanese)
https://tec.tecotec.co.jp/entry/2022/12/25/000000